# get Data form mySql and echo it - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need get Data form mySql and echo it . but show to me error ! please help me . I am amator . please check my code. (get Data form mySql and echo it - PHP)

my error in `$result1=mysqli_query($link,$query1);`

my PHP file :

```
<?php

$post_data=@$_POST['myjson'];
$post_data=json_decode($post_data,true);
$command=$post_data['command'];
$server="localhost";
$user="user";
$pass="pass";
$db="db";
$link=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");


if ($command=="get_contact") {
    $id=$post_data['id'];
    $query="select * from ad where id=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num == 1) {
        $query1="select * from user where id=$row['user_id']";
        $result1=mysqli_query($link,$query1);
        $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
        $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result1);

        if ($num1 == 1) {
            $specifications=array("mobile"=>$row1["mobile"], "email"=>$row1["email"]);
            echo "<b>".json_encode($specifications)."</b>";
        } else {
            echo "<b>Not Found</b>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "<b>Not Found</b>";
    }

    exit(); 
}

?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?  echo "<b>Error</b>" isn't very helpful.  at least change them to something like 'error 1' and 'error 2' so you know where it failed.  I assume you have PHP and a mysql database installed on localhost?

Comment: my error in `$result1=mysqli_query($link,$query1);`

Comment: then my guess the problem is with your query: $query1="select * from user where id=$row['user_id']";  It looks like you're encapsulate the $row varable as part of the string

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect just one result of each query, you can get the same results with just one query instead of the two you have:

```
$query = "select user.* from user, ad where ad.id=$id and user.id = ad.user_id";
```

Also, you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection instead of writing vars inside the sql queries.

Besides that, give more info in the error messages because now you don't know which error is returning.